# How do I prevent boxes from dropping down when browser size is reduced?

Tags: css, web, dreamweaver

3 columns 2 rows. so 6 boxes. 3 on first row and 3 on second row.
When I reduce the browser size, the box on the right side drops down to the next row. How do I keep boxes in its places when I reduce the browser size?

code:

```
 #content {
    width: 1200px;
    height: 840px;
    background-color: #f9fafa;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}


    .box {
    height: 355px;
    width: 355px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    display: block;
    }


<div id="content">
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't post a image because I don't have enough reputation points. I did show html.

Comment: using chrome, i don't see a problem with your code. the boxes are all staying in a 3x2 grid. http://jsfiddle.net/cxzejryr/

Comment: my only problem is, when I reduce the browser size, the far right boxes drop down to the next row. I want the boxes to be fixed when the browser is reduced.

Comment: what browser are you using? it's working for me even when shrinking the window.

Comment: Chrome, the boxes still drop down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this will fix your issue. There are many ways of accomplishing having 3 columns when you resize your browser and my fix was to set certain media queries and change the margin. Also changed the width from px to % so there's no horizontal scrolling.

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="content">
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
        <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

and the CSS

```
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 840px;
    background-color: #f9fafa;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
}
.box {
    height: 355px;
    width: 30%;
    background-color: red;
    border: 1px solid #323232;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -ms-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    -o-transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    transition: background-color 0s ease 0s;
    float: left;
    /*position: relative;*/
    margin: 20px;
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width:1270px) {
    .box { margin: 10px; }
}
@media (max-width:680px) {
    .box { margin: 5px; }
}
@media (max-width:400px) {
    .box { margin: 2px; }
}
```

As you can see, the media queries are just my own and as I'm resizing the browser, I am reducing my margin.

Hope this works.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I need the box width to be specifically 335px. will it still work?

Comment: Yes it works. Just follow the same concept as the margin I changed per media queries but this time just change the width of the .box to whatever it fits on that screen resolution. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Set the #content to have `min-width: 1200px;`.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/zbf30brf/

Comment: didn't work, I need the boxes to be fixed in their places if the browser is reduced.

Comment: the boxes are fixed in their places.  Look at the jsfiddle, is not behaving so?  I'm using chrome to test.  Can you take screenshots and post them to demonstrate your problem?  Show how it should look and how it currently looks on your browser.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation points so I can't upload images. Yes, they are fixed when the browser is 100% but if I drag and minimize from the right size of the browser, then the box drops down because it can no longer fit on the first row. hope you understand.